# Persist context variable between threads

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf

I am using .NET 4.0, ASP.NET & WCF. It's a multi-tier web service. I would like to record the caller id in the web tier and then use that id when querying the database in the data tier.

The issue is that the app uses a multi-threaded (implemented via .NET task library) business layer in between the web and data tiers. There are a lot of methods, so I want to avoid passing the caller ID as a parameter to each function in the business layer and then to each function in the data layer.

Is there a way to persist a value in a "call" context? HttpContext and OperationContext come to mind, but, to the best of my knowledge, they will not persist state when threads switch.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that HttpContext and OperationContext differ on a per-thread basis (they use Thread Local Storage, which is why).

But the solution I see is simple, just use a static class that you control, and said class would contain a publicly accessible dictionary for value lookups.

Comment: Not sure how to make it call-specific. It's a multi-user app, so if I save data into a static dictionary in the web tier, how would I know which key to use to look up that data in the data tier?

Comment: This is why you pass everything by argument :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use default ASP.NET authentication, you should be able to retrieve identity from

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity
```

But letting BL or DAL aware of `HttpContext` is not the best idea, you don't want to embed custom UI code into generic BL and DA layers. The usual flow is you create a user in UI (based on `HttpContext`), user has got some methods and properties (located in BL). One property is ID and methods can use this ID. Some people prefer to separate logic into separate services - these services shall take into all info they need to operate. Services shall get either a user or userId (if needed in your case).

If you design an application in this way, then multithreaded application will work fine. Each thread will have a local copy of the user. Context switch will load all the data a thread needs, giving there is no shared resources, each thread will have its own user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using authentication then go with the answer from Oleskii.

If not using authentication and you just want to track a session then

[HttpSessionState.SessionID Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

I think all threads will see the same value.